# javascript to disable checkbox

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts

I am a novice in UI technologies. any clue for solving below problem will be a great help.

Following is code for my jsp page

```
<label for="enableLogging"><s:text name="log.enable"/></label>
  <s:checkbox id="enableLogging" name="enableLogging" value="enableLogging" disabled="%{!user.system}"/>
  <div class=title><s:text name="sys.events"/></div>
    <label for="level"><s:text name="level"/> <s:select id="level" name="level" value="level" disabled="${disabled}"/></label>
    <label for="message"><s:text name="message"/> <s:select id="message" name="message" value="message" disabled="${disabled}"/></label>
    <label for="addSeverity"><s:text name="add.severity"/></label>
    <s:checkbox id="addSeverity" name="addSeverity" value="addSeverity" disabled="${disabled}"/>
```

...
following is the javascript that I added for disabling the textboxes and checkboxes based on the value of enableLogging

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {

    var $enableLogging = $('#enableLogging');
    var $level = $('#level');
    var $message = $('#message');
    var $addSeverity = $('#addSeverity')

    if (!$enableLogging.prop('checked')) {
      $level.attr('disabled', true);
      $message.attr('disabled', true);
      $addSeverity.attr('disabled', true);
    }

    $enableLogging.change(function() {
      $this = $(this);
      if ($this.prop('checked')) {
        $level.attr('disabled', false);
        $message.attr('disabled', false);
        $addSeverity.attr('disabled', false);
      } else {
        $level.attr('disabled', true);
        $message.attr('disabled', true);
        $addSeverity.attr('disabled', true);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

I want to disable "level", "message" and "addSeverity" based on the value of checkbox for "enableLogging" but above code seems not to be working

Comment: can you try `$enableLogging.is("checked")`

Comment: have you tried e.g. `$level.attr('disabled', 'disabled');`

Answer (score 0):

You can try for

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#enableLogging").click(function() {
if($("#enableLogging").prop("checked") == true) {
$("#level").prop('disabled',true);
$("#message").prop('disabled',true);
$("#addSeverity").prop('disabled',true);
}
else {
$("#level").prop('disabled',false);
$("#message").prop('disabled',false);
$("#addSeverity").prop('disabled',false);
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the way I implemented it,

Javascript now is:

```
 var fieldDisabled = $('#enableLogging').is(':checked');

$('#enableLogging').change(function() {
  $this = $(this);
  if ($this.prop('checked')) {
      fieldDisabled = false;
  } else {
      fieldDisabled = true;
  }
});
```

Added following code in jsp:

```
<label for="enableLogging"><s:text name="log.enable"/></label>
  <s:checkbox id="enableLogging" name="enableLogging" value="enableLogging" disabled="%{!user.system}"/>
  <s:set var="disabled">
    <s:if test="%{!user.system} || fieldDisabled == true">
       disabled="disabled"
    </s:if>
  </s:set>
  <div class=title><s:text name="sys.events"/></div>
    <label for="level"><s:text name="level"/> <s:select id="level" name="level" value="level" disabled="%{#disabled}"/></label>
    <label for="message"><s:text name="message"/> <s:select id="message" name="message" value="message" disabled="%{#disabled}"/></label>
    <label for="addSeverity"><s:text name="add.severity"/></label>
    <s:checkbox id="addSeverity" name="addSeverity" value="addSeverity" disabled="%{#disabled}"/>
```